# RegEx with date time and timezone

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx for date time and timezone.  I am looping through a long string for PC tech notes and I need to find the date time and timezone and then find the next space after a user ID.  The time zone is hard coded as "Eastern Standard Time - ".

My string looks like this:

```
10/18/2012 4:30 PM Eastern Standard Time - userID1 I rebooted the PC.  10/18/2012 4:30 PM Eastern Standard Time - userID2 The reboot that the other tech performed did not fix the issue.
```

The userID can be 6 or 8 characters long.  I want to find the index of the space after each instance and insert a line break.

I'm using ASP .NET 3.5 using C#.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where you want the new line.  Can you add the expected output for your example?

Comment: Every time that a new note is added to this column in my table there is an automatic stamp of date time Eastern Standard Time - userID and then whatever the tech typed in the trouble ticket follows.  The problem is that all of the entries get appended into this one column in the table - it's not my app - it's something my job purchased called TrackIt 10.5.  I want to find the index of the automatic stamp and place a new line before and after it using <br /> from my C# code behind.  This will help the clarity greatly for the end-user reading the output in my ASP .NET page.

Comment: Two other strings I want to do a match on in my large string.  A new line is 5 consecutive spaces in the large string, and 8 consecutive spaces is two new lines.  I would like to convert any instance of 5 spaces in a row to <br /> and 8 spaces in a row to <br /><br />

Answer (score 0):

You got an example here: [Demo](http://regexr.com?32jsn)

If you want to backreference the username, you just have to use `(\w{5,8})` before the `[^\.]`.

Comment: I need to find the date/time AM or PM first - I want each be on a new line.

Comment: 0 examples so it's not easy to understand you.

Comment: I got the RegEx match working.  Here is the code: `Regex dateTimeStamp = new Regex(@"(1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/(3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])/(?:[0-9]{2})?[0-9]{2}.([0]?[1-9]|[1][0-2]):([0-5][0-9]|[1-9]).[AP]M Eastern Standard Time - [a-z0-9_-]{6,8}");`  What I would like to do now is insert a line break after the first regex match and then insert a line break before and after every following regex match.  How do I do that in a loop through my string?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code:

```
protected string FormatTechNote(string note)
{
    //This method uses a regular expression to find each date time techID stamp
    //in a note on a ticket.  It finds the stamp and then adds spacing for clarity
    //while reading.

    //RegEx for Date Time Eastern Standard Time - techID (6 or 8 characters in techID)
    Regex dateTimeStamp = new Regex(@"((((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00))).([1-9]|1[012]):[0-5][0-9].[AP]M.Eastern Standard Time - [a-z0-9_-]{6,8})");

    MatchCollection matchList = dateTimeStamp.Matches(note);
    if (matchList.Count > 0)
    {
        //If at least one match occurs then insert a new line after that instance.
        Match firstMatch = matchList[0];

        note = Regex.Replace(note, matchList[0].Value, matchList[0].Value + "<br /><br />");

        //If more than one match occurs than insert a new line before and after each instance.
        if (matchList.Count > 1)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < matchList.Count; j++)
            {
                note = Regex.Replace(note, matchList[j].Value, "<br /><br /><br />" + matchList[j].Value + "<br /><br />");
            }
        }
    }

    //TrackIt uses 5 consecutive spaces for a new line in the note, and 8
    //consecutive spaces for two new lines.  Check for each and then
    //replace with new line(s).

    note = Regex.Replace(note, @"\s{8}", "<br /><br /><br />");

    note = Regex.Replace(note, @"\s{5}", "<br /><br />");

    return note;
}
```